# How to print on a specific paper

Tags: css, printing

I'm having problems with printing some text on a **A4** paper that has **24** labels.

Basically, in every row there are 3 labels in which comes the name, surname and adress of a person and that label will be used for mails ( it's a sticky label that is sticked on a mail).

[image: 70*36mm cell]

So this is the paper. Its characteristics:

1. There are **10 rows**.
2. The **first** and **last** row are the *smallest* and have `height:0.5mm;`.
3. In **first** and **last** row there are **no** cells.
4. All the rest rows have `height:36mm;`.
5. All the cells have `width:70mm;` and `height:36mm;`.
6. In every cell comes a text that is `text-align:center;` and `vertical-align:middle;`.

I'm using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for *css reset*.

**CSS**

```
html,body,table{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.first, .last{
  width: 100%;
  height: 5mm;
}

.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 36mm;
}

.cell{
  width: 70mm;
  height: 36mm;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I'm using **Chrome** and I turned off the **margins** on printing.

But still, the last two rows are printed on the **next page**.
I need all 10 rows on the same page and that their position is fixed ( doesn't shift ) in case if there are multiple pages.

How to fix/achieve that ? Or is there a simpler solution ?

Here is an example of the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/cBX6g/).

Comment: recently I've faced a similar problem and I've solved it by creating a pdf page and then print it. If you have no problem using pdf then i can post my solution here. Thanks.

Comment: @maksbd19 I0m open to all solutions. Please post :)

Comment: the sum of the heights is 298mm wich is 1mm longer tha A4 (21x297). Also notice that printer can't print border to border theyneed some margins. Maybe you can get rid of first and last rows and play with cells height in order to make them fit.

Comment: @Ateszki will take you comment under notice. I will remove the first and last row and increase the height of the first and last inner row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `FPDF` class to create a pdf for my labels.

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/path/to/fpdf.php';


class PDF_MC_Table extends FPDF{
    var $widths;
    var $aligns;

    function SetWidths($w){
        //Set the array of column widths
        $this->widths=$w;
    }   
    function SetAligns($a){
        //Set the array of column alignments
        $this->aligns=$a;
    }   
    function Row($data){
        //Calculate the height of the row
        $nb=0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
        $h = 36;// again trial and error until you fnd the desired height of your label
        //Issue a page break first if needed
        $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
        //Draw the cells of the row
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
            $w=$this->widths[$i];
            $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
            //Save the current position
            $x=$this->GetX();
            $y=$this->GetY();
            //Draw the border. reset the parameters of the function below as you desire.
            $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
            //Print the text. reset the parameters of the function below as you desire. changing the values will resize the boxs.
            $this->MultiCell($w,3,$data[$i],0,$a);
            //Put the position to the right of the cell. reset the parameters of the function below as you desire. changing the $x and $y will shift the cells.
            $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
        }
        //Go to the next line
        $this->Ln($h+3);
    }

    function CheckPageBreak($h){
        //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
        if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
            $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
    }

    function NbLines($w,$txt){  
        //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
        $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
        if($w==0)
            $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
        $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
        $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
        $nb=strlen($s);
        if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
            $nb--;
        $sep=-1;
        $i=0;
        $j=0;
        $l=0;
        $nl=1;
        while($i<$nb){
            $c=$s[$i];
            if($c=="\n"){
                $i++;
                $sep=-1;
                $j=$i;
                $l=0;
                $nl++;
                continue;
            }
            if($c==' ')
                $sep=$i;
            $l+=$cw[$c];
            if($l>$wmax){
                if($sep==-1){
                    if($i==$j)
                        $i++;
                }
                else
                    $i=$sep+1;
                $sep=-1;
                $j=$i;
                $l=0;
                $nl++;
            }
            else
                $i++;
        }
        return $nl;
    }
}

$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->SetMargins(4, 2);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
// displays the empty row in the top
$pdf->SetRightMargin(2);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(4);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'',1);
$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->SetWidths(array(50,50,50));// these are the widths of your cells. this is a trial and error process. increase the values until you find the suitable ones.

$count = 0;


$lables = array(); // your labels array

$l = array();
$j = 0;

// i used this foreach for breaking my plain array into a 2dimentional array- an array of arrays consisting 3 labels in each.

foreach($lables as $i=>$lbl  ){
    $l[$j][] = $lbl;

    if($i%3==2){$j++;} // $i=0,1,2 > $j=0; $i=3,4,5 > $j=2 etc this will break the main labels array as 2D array.
}
// displays the empty row in the bottom.
$pdf->Ln(1);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'',1);

$pdf->Output();
```

for further information about the class and methods please refer to http://www.fpdf.org/ At best you need to understand three methods- Multicell(), Cell() and Rect() methods. There are pretty nice explanation of these methods with examples in the site.

Here i've posted my solution and i've changed some code based on your problem. Most of the things are self explanatory. If you need further assist please feel free to comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank for the answer, will definitely try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

reduce the cell and row height sizes if you are no using the sizes in specific, what happens even after turning off margins, printing data goes out of paper length and printer moves it to another page automatically.

thats the best solution i think you can try.

p.s: these kinds of sticky labels usually come with their design software cd which you usually use to set the margins with preview. if you dont have it, only thing you can do is maually adjust the heights as i told above, print on a normal A4 plain paper and tele with the sticky label paper. I used to do it too... worked for me though

Comment: I will try to lower the height of the cells. Hope it will work. No software came with the paper , that's why I have to make this work.

Comment: Are you ware that the cells current have a padding of 1px? That might be what's throwing your layout off

Comment: @Dre you mean on padding which comes from browsers default settings ?

Comment: well, i also tested your provided css and other codes and checked their print layout, reducing the sizes as suggested will make it print on one paper.. secondly manually calibrate it with sticky label paper using an A4 print.

Also note that everytime you stock paper in printer tray, print will come a little different from old printed A4 paper. It is because of the paper position in tray. so make sure while calibrating, paper has to be in more or less same position before the roller in printer pulls it up.

Comment: That's a bit complicated to manually adjust the papers in the tray. I am still sure that it's a CSS problem, because on every page the page text goes higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try borderless printing if your printer supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the styling below and playing with the @page attributes. More info in @page can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page

I've had good luck using the styles defined below to print perfectly on 8.5x11 documents where I can set my own margin and have consistent results out of the browser.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  }
  body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #000 ;
    margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the content before sending to printer */
    padding: 0.25in 0.5in;
  }
</style>
```